# Angular Bootstrap button size

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6

I'm using Angular 6 for my Project and it integrates with bootstrap. I'm using

```
'<button class="btn btn-info">ADD</button>'
```

but my button looks a bit bigger than usual when it comes to a height which makes the UI looks bit ugly! Kindly give me a solution to solve this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1tof.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just inspect your code and find the padding for your button and override those values with new values in your .css file

If you are using Bootstrap 4 buttons you can use these to override:

```
.btn {
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem !important;
}
```

**Note: Padding values may change according to your button size**

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 provides below button size :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Default</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Small</button>
```

Use as per you requirement. If you want to customize your own you can use override them or create new one with desires **font-size**.